# Can I add a partial view to an existing MVC5 project?

Tags: model-view-controller, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

I need to implement a Telerik control into an existing page of a MVC5 project.

The problem is that I don't own the source code of the project  (it's an off the shelf framework) so  when I open it in VS there is not the model and controller files (only the shared view) so I cannot modify it accordingly to my needs. The shared view is a cshtml file with pure HTML stuffed with a bunch of HTML helpers and a couple Razor blocks.

Since I am pretty new in MVC I would like to know if it's possible that I create a custom "partial view" from scratch inside this project and invoke it from the shared view.

- I am asking the feasibility of it before I waste a lot of time chasing my own tail on something that cannot be done... :/

Comment: MVC = Model View Controller... if you add a new Razor View... you need to add controller code and a model to pass to the view. So, I think you can't create new ones. You can modify the HTML part and use the Model information to do "new things".

Comment: Thanks for this! I think I will just add an iframe and run the web form within it then!